# How do I keep a span from being at the end of a line?

Tags: html, css, formatting, styles

Let's say that I have a paragraph element containing several different types of spans that delegate the css style with classes. If I had numbers wrapped in with the rest of the text that serve as place-markers for easy reference, how could I keep those numbers from being at the end of a wrapping line?

E.g.

```
1 This is some text that
wraps. 2 I don't want any
of these numbers 3 to end
up at the end of one of these
lines. For this example, 4
this number shouldn't be at
the end of the line.
```

Sorry if this is a little sloppy, but it's the only way I can think of to describe it. Each of those numbers is contained in its own span that give it a class name. I want to find the right css or whatnot that will keep it from being the last object in the line.

I considered using some margin-right length on the number spans, and then adding a negative margin-left at the beginning of the next text span, but I want this to be a flexible solution that can cover all cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a non breaking space (`&nbsp;`) between the number and the first word then the browser will wrap it with the next word. Like this: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RfDLy/))

```html
1&nbsp;This is some text that wraps. 2&nbsp;I don't want anyof these numbers 3&nbsp;to end up at the end of one of these lines. For this example, 4&nbsp;this number shouldn't be at the end of the line.
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. I use plenty of nonbreaking spaces, but I've never tied in the fact that it's name is "non-breaking" for a reason. Chalk one up for being unobservant. lol thanks.